# Drools 6.4 Multiple modify and named consequences

Tags: java, drools, rules

I am pretty new in Drools and I would like to know if is it possible to trigger the modify/update fact only when the RHS is ended.

Look for this sample :

```
rule "test"
    when
        $o1 : MyObject( isNew == null ) // isNew is a Boolean()
        do[initNew]
        $o2 : MySecondObject( name = "ABC" )
    then
       ... //do stuff
       modify($o1) { setNew(true) }; //set to true if we arrived here
       modify($o2) { setName("DEF") };
    then[initNew]
       ... //do stuff
       modify($o1) { setNew(false) }; //init to false
end
```

In this sample, I would like to set `isNew` to `false` there is no `$o2` in facts, otherwise is want to set it to `true`.

When I test this rule, the `do[initNew]` is called, the modify is fired so the rule is instantly replay and the `then` part is never called....

An idea ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lure of procedural programming has been introduced with do[] and then[]. Stick to clean logic - what you need is two rules:

```
rule "test Second true"
when
    $o1 : MyObject( isNew == null ) // isNew is a Boolean()
    $o2 : MySecondObject( name = "ABC" )
then
    modify($o1) { setNew(true) };
    modify($o2) { setName("DEF") };
end

rule "test Second missing"
when
    $o1 : MyObject( isNew == null ) // isNew is a Boolean()
    not MySecondObject( name = "ABC" )
then
    modify($o1) { setNew(false) }; //init to false
end
```

Comment: Yep you're right, i need to always keep in mind to write a rule for each different consequences. Thanks